# "data argument not used by format string " error after xcode upgrade

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

```
#define IMAGE_PATH @"/Users/jinyoung85/Desktop/test1"
```

up code has (data argument not used by format string ) error after upgrading xcode 4.4.

why? how do i solve this problem?

Comment: That line of code is not what's causing the error. Almost certainly you have a format string (e.g. `+[NSString stringWithFormat:]`) that defines some `n` number of format tokens but has some `n+1` number of arguments.

Comment: Above comment your answer for sure !